# Let $X$, $Y$ be independent and both uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and compute $E[XY\mid X+Y]$

Tags: probability

I tried $E[(X+Y)^2\mid X+Y] =(X+Y)^2$ and expand it as
$$E[X^2\mid X+Y] + E[Y^2\mid X+Y] + E[XY\mid X+Y].$$
But still no idea how I can compute $E[X^2\mid X+Y]$.

Anyone can help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method for computing $E(X^{2}|X+Y)$. You can write this as $f(X+Y)$ for some measurable function $f$ which is determined by the condition $EX^{2}I_{\{X+Y \leq t\}} =Ef(X+Y)I_{\{X+Y \leq t\}}$ for all $t$. If $0 \leq t \leq 1$ you get $\int_0^{t} f(u)\, du =\int_0^{t} x^{2}(t-x) \, dx$ which gives ( on differentiation) $f(t)=\frac {t^{3}} 3$. Do a similar computation for $t$ between $1$ and $2$. Once you find $f$ we can conclude that $E(Y^{2}|X+Y)=E(X^{2}|X+Y)=Ef(X+Y)$ because $(X,Y)$ has the same distribution as $(Y,X)$. You can now write down $E(XY|X+Y)$ easily.